# How can I extract many sublists at once in R?

Tags: r, list, sublist

I am new to R and dealing with this large list called "times.list" (see image)   [List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9hGN.jpg).
Here, to extract my vectors from 1 to 4 (marked in red) I just "unlist" each one of them, and create new objects like so:

```
data1 <- unlist(times.list [[1]] [1])
data2 <- unlist(times.list [[1]] [2])
data3 <- unlist(times.list [[1]] [3])
data4 <- unlist(times.list [[1]] [4])
```

Instead of doing this over and over x the number of vectors I have (my list is [1x113] in this case), is there a way to extract these data at once, and assign a name to all of them? Ideally I would like to extract only a subset (in this example data2, data4) based on a vector:

dataIneed <- c(2, 4)

Thank you so much!

Based on my vector:

```
dataIneed
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
2   4
```

I do:

```
data2 <- unlist(times.list [[1]] [2])
data4 <- unlist(times.list [[1]] [4])
```

It works perfectly but it's not practical at all, it takes forever because in reality I have >100 vectors to extract.

Comment: `times.list[[1]][dataIneed]` should do it.

Comment: Yes! It works, thank you! Now I have a list [60] with the data I want. Each one of the 60 elements is a vector (double nx1). Can I create 60 new objects containing these vectors at once?

Comment: You _can_ make 60 new objects, but doing so makes no sense. Leave them in a list so you don't pollute your workspace. If they are in a list you can access them easily and iterate over them in a way that you can't if they are separate objects. Why would you have them as separate objects?

Comment: OK great! Let's say I want to make a data frame with them. I can go one by one creating n new objects: 

`one<- unlist(mylist [1])`
`two<- unlist(mylist [2])`
`df<- data.frame(one, two)`

How can I do this keeping my data in the list?

Answer (score 1):

To extract multiple elements of a list, use indexing: `mylist[index]`.

`as.data.frame(mylist)` is sufficient to convert your list to a `data.frame`. You do *not ever* need to put your columns into separate variables first, and doing so is convoluted and pollutes your global environment with unnecessary temporary variables. If you want to assign custom column names you can then use `setNames()`.

If you want to extract sublists/unlist, `lapply(mylist, unlist)` is your friend.

Putting it all together:

```
extracted_data <- lapply(times.list[dataIneed], unlist)
result <- setNames(as.data.frame(extracted_data), paste0("data", dataIneed))
```